# Pass parameters to a modal - ColdFusion

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to pass parameters to a user profile modal when I press on their name. My table is generated dynamically with a loop and one of the values is something like this:

```
   <td><a href="##" data-reveal-id="profileModal" 
          data-id="#ContactID#">Take Action</a>
   </td>
```

I was attempting to use `data-id` to pass in the contactID of each user, but I don't know how to use the parameter when my modal opens. At the moment I am using

```
   <td><a href="/admin/_guestProfile.cfm?contactid=#ContactID#" 
           target="_blank" >Take Action</a>
   </td>
```

which is opening a new window and I am passing the parameter through the url, but I don't like this from a user experience point.

How can I take the data-id value and use it for operations inside my modal. Is there a better way than what I am attempting to accomplish?

The name of the plugin that I am using is `jQuery Reveal Plugin 1.1` and this is the website that contains the code for it http://www.zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

Comment: Is there a question in your post?

Comment: I thought so... Let me edit it real quick

Comment: What do you mean by "user profile modal"? If you mean opening a modal window with javascript, we need to see the javascript code. Please note any external javascript libraries you are using.

Comment: I will update my post to include the javascript files Leigh. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the plugin you're using is very light on features. What you need to do is pull in an iframe so the guest profile can be updated. Since you're using jquery already, why not just use the diag in juqeryui. here is a wrapper plugin for it that will invoke an iframe:

https://github.com/miyabis/jquery.iframeDialog

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are referring to some kind of javascript action, like this:

```
  <a onclick="javascript:openModal(#ContactID#);" href=...>
```

where openModal() is a javascript function you need to define somewhere.
AA very easy way to implement modal through jquery is http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/